# Flutter how to update text on dropdownbutton when using Sqflite to populate the list

Tags: dart, flutter

I have no problem populating the list from Sqflite database on DropdownButton.  My only problem is updating the text once it's selected.   It kept showing 'Airport' and I'm still learning to work with Object instead of String.  I just couldn't figure that out.

Here's the code:

```
String selectedAirport;
AirportModel _currentAirport;
...

children: <Widget>[

                FutureBuilder<List<AirportModel>>(
                    future: db.getAllAirports(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AirportModel>> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      return DropdownButton<AirportModel>(
                        items: snapshot.data
                            .map((airportItem) =>
                            DropdownMenuItem<AirportModel>(
                              value: airportItem,
                              child: Text(airportItem.airportName),
                            ))
                            .toList(),
                        onChanged: (AirportModel value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentAirport = value;
                            selectedAirport = _currentAirport.airportName;
                          });
                        },
                        hint: Text("Airport"),
                      );
                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

DropdownButton has a property `value`. use it like `value=_currentAirport`

```
return DropdownButton<AirportModel>(
    value:_currentAirport,
    items: snapshot.data
        .map((airportItem) =>
        DropdownMenuItem<AirportModel>(
          value: airportItem,
          child: Text(airportItem.airportName),
        ))
        .toList(),
    onChanged: (AirportModel value) {
      setState(() {
        _currentAirport = value;
        selectedAirport = _currentAirport.airportName;
      });
    },
    hint: Text("Airport"),
);
```

Comment: I appreciate it but I got this error..
    'I/flutter ( 9384): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null ||
I/flutter ( 9384): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
I/flutter ( 9384): value).length == 1': is not true.'

Comment: It's not a problem of answer what I have provided. Please make sure `snapshot.data` is not null

Comment: I'm still stuck with this issue.  How do I make sure snapshot.data is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe items didn't reach yet or empty when value is set to DropdownButton. is _currentAirport initialized to some other value already?

Can you try like this? Also check if the items list are empty

```
items: snapshot.data == null ? null : _currentAirport
```

Comment: It didn't solved it.   Here's the initialization. AirportModel _currentAirport; String selectedAirport;   I got 'error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the class 'AirportModel'. (undefined_method at [pilotvoice] lib\CustomScreen.dart:66)'   any suggestion?

Comment: What is the type of airportItem that you're using map() on?

Comment: I didn't initialize airportItem to any type except that there's callback for it.  I use this [link] (https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-populate-dropdownbutton-using-sqlite-database-in-flutter/) example.

Comment: I think it's better to check (snapshot.hasData) before rendering just like the example from your link. Or you can render loading indicator while (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)

Comment: It has Data where I can see the list is being populated from the database.  However, I'm still unable to show what I selected to update the text inside the dropdownbutton "text field"

Comment: DropdownButton needs 'value' property. Maybe did you miss it?
 https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Comment: I dont think that's it.  It seems that whenever onchanged ..it automatically try to SELECT * from database according to debugging.  getAllAirports is in Futurebuilder. I dont want them to do that everytime I select an item from dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a Future and init in initState and in FutureBuilder use this future.

```
AirportModel _currentAirport;;
Future _future;

@override
  void initState() {
    _future = db.getAllAirports();
    super.initState();
  }

body: FutureBuilder<List<AirportModel>>(
          future: _future,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream builder. Please check the example below.

```
class DropDownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DropDownMenuState createState() => _DropDownMenuState();
}

class _DropDownMenuState extends State<DropDownMenu> {
  var _currentSelectedValue;
  final _dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  LoginPageManager _loginPageManager = new LoginPageManager();
  final ValueNotifier<List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>> _dropDownMenuItems =
      ValueNotifier<List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>>([]);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _updateList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 300,
      height: 50,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 00.0),
      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list,
            Widget child) {
          return Container(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: Text("Please Select a Server"),
                value: _currentSelectedValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentSelectedValue = value;
                  });
                },
                items: list),
          );
        },
        valueListenable: _dropDownMenuItems,
      ),
    );
  }

  _updateList() async {
    print("Update server has been called");
    _dropDownMenuItems.value.clear();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> x = await _dbHelper.queryAllRows();
    _dropDownMenuItems.value.add(_getAddServerButton());
    x.forEach((element) {
      _dropDownMenuItems.value.add(_getDropDownWidget(element));
    });
  }

  DropdownMenuItem<String> _getDropDownWidget(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    int id = map['yxz'];
    String text =
        map['xyz'];
    String value = map['zyx'];
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Container(
          width: 270,
          child: Row(
            children: [_getText(text), _getRemoveButton(id), _getEditButton(id)],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure api data is not null:

```
child: _identity1 != null

          ? DropdownButtonFormField<dynamic>(

              validator: (value) => value == null ? 'field required' : null
```